# elementary OS 0.4 text is too light. Can I make it darker?

Tags: desktop, themes

I am using elementary OS version 0.3.2 and it works just fine. I tried elementary OS version 0.4 and the text on everything is too light. Both of these have been used on a desktop computer. Is there a way to make the text darker on version 0.4?

Answer (score 1):

The method that [Daniel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/45/daniel-for%C3%A9) would prefer is to use dconf-editor. Once installed (from the AppCenter), Ctrl-f and search for color, keep hitting 'next' until you find the one that applies to font color.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Elementary Tweaks: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/4p3yei/elementary_tweaks_on_loki/

There you can easily change the system fonts.